# How to send message in shash command using event?

Tags: python-3.x, nextcord

I want send message from event to specific channel

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message_edit(self, before: nextcord.Message, after: nextcord.Message):
        e = nextcord.Embed(color = before.author.color, timestamp = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc))
        #some code
        channel = channel_id
```

How can I solve this problem?